# Algorithm to simulate in real time some liquid in a 2D container

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, simulation, fluid

I'm looking for some algorithms (or some applets/examples with source code) to simulate fluids in a 2D container (which can be moved and rotated).

An example of what I need is a 2D glass with some water inside, like the iBeer application for smart phones.

Comment: your question is very general, you should specify exactly which kind of detail you need in your simulation, and then have a look at some undergraduate text in computational fluid dynamics

Comment: @Werner: what do you mean by "detail"? What options do I have? Having to learn fluid dynamics to simulate water sounds like an overkill to me...

Comment: I mean, how realistic you want to do your simulation. I would read some review or general article about fluid dynamics so you can understand where to look for algorithms/methods and so, and which are the advantages/disadvantages on each case

Comment: @Werner: it's hard to qualify how realistic I want it. The best the hardware can do in real time (and here the question is "how is your hardware? how much fluid do you need to simulate?" "it varies a lot, it depends, I'm not sure"). I started this question right to obtain a list of algorithms/methods to look at, because I couldn't find any good (and simple - I'm not a physician) one. Besides most (almost all) of the documentation I could find is about _pools_ of fluid seen from above, or for 3D liquid simulation, which is not what I need.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427151/algorithms-for-simulating-fluid-flow

Comment: @Werner: I was hoping for something more specialized on what I need, but probably there's nothing like that. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: you said you are not a physicist. if you want something more realistic you should get some background in physics. the solutions they propose there are quite good in the cases one is not a specialist. we should always try to be in an equilibrium between what we want and what we can do, in my modest opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after are "sloshing algorithms", some of them are specifically designed for cross-sections.

Comment: Could you provide some links?